# Cannot figure out how to write MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a MySQL select statement which will use `table1` and `table2` to generate a `table3`.

table1

| id | Month | Year | Name | Length | Breath |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | January | 2002 | Square | 5 | 2 |
| 2 | February | 2003 | Circle | 6 | 3 |
| 3 | March | 2004 | Cylinder | 7 | 4 |
| 4 | April | 2005 | Cube | 8 | 5 |
| 5 | May | 2006 | Quadilateral | 9 | 6 |

table2

| id | Month | Year | Name | Frequency | Area | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | January | 2002 | Square | 1 | 20 | 50 |
| 2 | Febrauy | 2003 | Circle | 2 | 25 | 55 |
| 3 | March | 2004 | Cylinder | 3 | Null | 60 |
| 4 | April | 2005 | Cube | 4 | 35 | 65 |
| 5 | May | 2006 | Quadilateral | 5 | 40 | Null |

table3 the generated table should be like this.

| Name | Type | Month | Year | Length | Breath | Frequency | Volume/Area | Cum_Area | Cum_Volume | Area | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Square | 2d | January | 2002 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 2.5 | 20 | 50 | 20 | 50 |
| Circle | 2d | February | 2003 | 6 | 3 | 2 | 2.2 | 45 | 105 | 25 | 55 |
| Cylinder | 3d | March | 2004 | 7 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 45 | 165 | 30 | 60 |
| Cube | 3d | April | 2005 | 8 | 5 | 4 | 1.86 | 80 | 230 | 35 | 65 |
| Quadilateral | 4d | May | 2006 | 9 | 6 | 5 | 1.75 | 120 | 230 | 40 | 70 |

In the statements I've tried whenever the cumulative column encounters the first null value, every row from then on is null.

Also, how do I write the type column? I'd like square and circle to be '2d'; cube and cylinder to be '3d' and Quadrilateral to be '4d'.

Table 1 and 2 have the Name, Month and Year column in common.

Comment: Join the two tables using the columns they have in common. Use a `CASE` expression for the `Type` column.

Comment: what is the condition for type? What is your logic? Please read the tutorial, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Why is a quadrilateral 4d? In geometry, a quadrilateral is a 2-dimensional shape with 4 sides.

Comment: This is just dummy data and figures, since I can't share the real data and also it's way too large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't finish to understand what is your logic or why you don't have ids on the second table. But assuming what you write, this is a SUGGESTION.
Update your question I'll glad to update my answer.

Assuming null means 0:

```
SELECT
table1.Name,
CASE table1.Name 
WHEN Square THEN '2d'
WHEN Circle THEN '2d'
WHEN Cylinder THEN '3d'
WHEN Cube THEN '3d'
WHEN Quadilateral THEN '4d'
END as Type,
table1.Month,
table1.Year,
table1.Length,
table1.Breath,
table2.Frequency,
(IFNULL(table2.Volume,0) / IFNULL(table2.Area,0)) as 'Volume/Area',
//I don't understand what do you need in this field,
//I don't understand what do you need in this field,
table2.Area,
table2.Volume
FROM table1 
JOIN table2
ON table1.Name = table2.Name AND table1.Month = table2.Month AND table1.Year = table2.Year
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The two fields you omitted what I need there is the cumulative addition of the Area and Volume columns. Kind of like a running sum for both. That is actually the part of the problem which is giving me the most trouble and prompted this question.

Comment: @danielajj ok, no problem. Let me understand so I can edit my answer. Let's try with the example of Circle. You get 105 in Cum_Volume because you have (for eg) three records in table2 with Circle: one with 55, one with 20 and another with 30?

Comment: Sorry, I have a follow up question from this question. I want the order the generated table by 'Type'. so I add the order by statement to the first table. But some rows which don't follow the ORDER BY clause are atop the generated table.